# File read write is not working

Tags: php

I am using a basic file read write function in a middle ware of slim framework 3.

```
$file = __DIR__ . '\\result.json';
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Cannot open files:  '.$file);
```

this file exist and path is correct. I also have the permission to read and write the file.

The result is showing cannot open files.

Please suggest how a simple read and write function will work in slim framework 3.

Comment: Well there is no difference in opening files in slim, are you sure that this path exists why do you use a double backslash (\\\) inside your file path?

Comment: I have tried with (\), (/) both, and when I am echo $file it is showing right path. I am sure about the right path of file.

Comment: use [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) for this

Comment: No success... I have tried this also `$my_file = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'result.json';`

Comment: remove or die() and [enable error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and or look at you php log for exceptions

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem. Change the permissions of your folder to include write permissions

Comment: Not Slim issue. Most likely your webserver does not have write access to the file. See  your error logs.

Comment: file exist is not necessary because handler with 'w' `$fh = fopen($file, 'w')`
check as die($file); and you see path to file.
possible that the path wrong